# Jquery countdown timer with input time and play pause options

Tags: jquery, html

I need a countdown timer that can get start time(minute) from input and start it after clicking start button
It also should have pause/play button 
I've been searching and just found some count down that get a date in theyr function

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please write your code here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something similar to stopwatch plugin. Look at these plugins.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/stopwatch/

They have set time,play and resume controls.

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

so i found something from jsfiddle in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/V2S9d/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function($){
    
        $.extend({
            
            APP : {                
                
                formatTimer : function(a) {
                    if (a < 10) {
                        a = '0' + a;
                    }                              
                    return a;
                },    
                
                startTimer : function(dir) {
                    
                    var a;
                    
                    // save type
                    $.APP.dir = dir;
                    
                    // get current date
                    $.APP.d1 = new Date();
                    
                    switch($.APP.state) {
                            
                        case 'pause' :
                            
                            // resume timer
                            // get current timestamp (for calculations) and
                            // substract time difference between pause and now
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime() - $.APP.td;                            
                            
                        break;
                            
                        default :
                            
                            // get current timestamp (for calculations)
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime(); 
                            
                            // if countdown add ms based on seconds in textfield
                            if ($.APP.dir === 'cd') {
                                $.APP.t1 += parseInt($('#cd_seconds').val())*1000;
                            }    
                        
                        break;
                            
                    }                                   
                    
                    // reset state
                    $.APP.state = 'alive';   
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Running');
                    
                    // start loop
                    $.APP.loopTimer();
                    
                },
                
                pauseTimer : function() {
                    
                    // save timestamp of pause
                    $.APP.dp = new Date();
                    $.APP.tp = $.APP.dp.getTime();
                    
                    // save elapsed time (until pause)
                    $.APP.td = $.APP.tp - $.APP.t1;
                    
                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Resume');
                    
                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'pause';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Paused');
                    
                },
                
                stopTimer : function() {
                    
                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');                    
                    
                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'stop';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Stopped');
                    
                },
                
                resetTimer : function() {

                    // reset display
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms,#' + $.APP.dir + '_s,#' + $.APP.dir + '_m,#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html('00');                 
                    
                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Start');                    
                    
                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'reset';  
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Reset & Idle again');
                    
                },
                
                endTimer : function(callback) {
                   
                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');
                    
                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'end';
                    
                    // invoke callback
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback();
                    }    
                    
                },    
                
                loopTimer : function() {
                    
                    var td;
                    var d2,t2;
                    
                    var ms = 0;
                    var s  = 0;
                    var m  = 0;
                    var h  = 0;
                    
                    if ($.APP.state === 'alive') {
                                
                        // get current date and convert it into 
                        // timestamp for calculations
                        d2 = new Date();
                        t2 = d2.getTime();   
                        
                        // calculate time difference between
                        // initial and current timestamp
                        if ($.APP.dir === 'sw') {
                            td = t2 - $.APP.t1;
                        // reversed if countdown
                        } else {
                            td = $.APP.t1 - t2;
                            if (td <= 0) {
                                // if time difference is 0 end countdown
                                $.APP.endTimer(function(){
                                    $.APP.resetTimer();
                                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Ended & Reset');
                                });
                            }    
                        }    
                        
                        // calculate milliseconds
                        ms = td%1000;
                        if (ms < 1) {
                            ms = 0;
                        } else {    
                            // calculate seconds
                            s = (td-ms)/1000;
                            if (s < 1) {
                                s = 0;
                            } else {
                                // calculate minutes   
                                var m = (s-(s%60))/60;
                                if (m < 1) {
                                    m = 0;
                                } else {
                                    // calculate hours
                                    var h = (m-(m%60))/60;
                                    if (h < 1) {
                                        h = 0;
                                    }                             
                                }    
                            }
                        }
                      
                        // substract elapsed minutes & hours
                        ms = Math.round(ms/100);
                        s  = s-(m*60);
                        m  = m-(h*60);                                
                        
                        // update display
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms').html($.APP.formatTimer(ms));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_s').html($.APP.formatTimer(s));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_m').html($.APP.formatTimer(m));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html($.APP.formatTimer(h));
                        
                        // loop
                        $.APP.t = setTimeout($.APP.loopTimer,1);
                    
                    } else {
                    
                        // kill loop
                        clearTimeout($.APP.t);
                        return true;
                    
                    }  
                    
                }
                    
            }    
        
        });
          
        $('#sw_start').on('click', function() {
            $.APP.startTimer('sw');
        });    

        $('#cd_start').on('click', function() {
            $.APP.startTimer('cd');
        });           
        
        $('#sw_stop,#cd_stop').on('click', function() {
            $.APP.stopTimer();
        });
        
        $('#sw_reset,#cd_reset').on('click', function() {
            $.APP.resetTimer();
        });  
        
        $('#sw_pause,#cd_pause').on('click', function() {
            $.APP.pauseTimer();
        });                
                
    })(jQuery);
        
});
```

```css
input {
    padding:4px;}

input[type="text"] {
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;}    

div {
    font-family:Arial,Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    width:360px;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    padding:16px;
    border:solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0 16px 0;}

div span:last-child {
color:green;}

h1 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 0 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
    <span id="sw_h">00</span>:
    <span id="sw_m">00</span>:
    <span id="sw_s">00</span>:
    <span id="sw_ms">00</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Start" id="sw_start" />
    <input type="button" value="Pause" id="sw_pause" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop"  id="sw_stop" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset" id="sw_reset" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span id="sw_status">Idle</span>
</div>
<div>
    Don't run them at the same time ... it's a demo :-)
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Countdown</h1>
    <span id="cd_h">00</span>:
    <span id="cd_m">00</span>:
    <span id="cd_s">00</span>:
    <span id="cd_ms">00</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Start" id="cd_start" />
    <input type="button" value="Pause" id="cd_pause" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop"  id="cd_stop" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset" id="cd_reset" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="15" id="cd_seconds" />
    secs
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span id="cd_status">Idle</span>
</div>
```

hope it helps